# Dynamically updated recyclerView

Tags: android

So let's say I have an app with recylcerView's items need to be updated every second (timer app, for example).

The only way I can think of is using TimerTask that calls **notifyDataSetChanged()** every second

Is this the optimal way? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is *really* necessary for you to update the list every one second or you could update it *after something happened*?

Comment: @joaquin in a timer app yes, it is necessary

Comment: The better way I feel would be to set the widget in the view but initiate it in onBindViewHolder(). Can you post the code for the timer app? That way you need not call notifyDataSetChanged() every time

Comment: @VarunAgarwal the code is waaaay to big to post, sorry. I understand what you mean though, that does not seem like a good idea, honestly, but perhaps I will give it a try

Comment: Initiating a code in on bind view holder won't take as much as having a perennial runnable running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're doing it right. Also, you could use a `Handler`:

```
final Handler h = new Handler();
h.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        //Update the list here (by calling notifyDataSetChanged(), for example)

        h.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
});
```

Then, you know that code will be executed every 1000 milliseconds (AKA 1 second).